# C# Serialization of numerics with suffixes

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

Is there some library for C#, or classes in .Net, that serializes numeric values with their corresponding suffixes to differentiate between e.g. signed and unsigned, int and long.

For example, I want the following serializition behavior:

```
ulong value = 123456789;
string valueStr = ToString(value);    

// valueStr == "123456789ul"
```

and a way to deserialize it, e.g.:

```
object parsedValue;
Type parsedType;
ParseNumeric(out parsedValue, out parsedType);    

// parsedValue == 123456789 (as an ulong)
// parsedType == typeof(ulong)
```

I need it to handle at least float, double, int, uint, long, ulong.

I've actually already wrote some naive code for this, but I'm wondering if there is anything out there already made for this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use DataContractSerializer and pass in `typeof(object)` as the declared type, you should get the behavior you want.